# Using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can anyone help me with it:
Using the central limit theorem for suitable Poisson random variables, prove that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}=1/2$$
Thanks!

Comment: This question has been asked and answered [countless](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297553) times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: A Poisson$(n)$ random variable can be represented as the sum of $n$ i.i.d. Poisson$(1)$ rv's.

Comment: I'll give further hints if you wish.

Comment: @Shai Covo: Can you show me the steps? Thanks!

Comment: @kira: Hint 2: Move the exponent into the sum.

Comment: @kira: Find a random variable $X$ for which it holds ${\rm P}(X=n) = \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{e^{ - n} n^k }}{{k!}}} $.