# How to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-n}\left(1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}\cdots+\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)$

Tags: limits

There is a probabilistic method to solve it. But I am not familiar with probability. I am trying to compute it by analytic method, such as using L Hospital's rule or Stolz formula, but they are not working.

Comment: Well, $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}=e^n-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}$. That seems like a place to start.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, and has been asked many times before on this very site.

Comment: The expression after $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ is the probability that a Poisson-distributed random variable with expected value $n$ is $\le n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: An interesting related fact: $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-n} \left ( 1+1/n \right )^{n^2} = e^{-1/2}$. This is probably easier to prove (you can just use L'Hospital's rule), and hints that this problem is not that simple (i.e. it will need something relatively tight), since the answer is neither $0$ nor $1$.

Comment: There's no need to delete this question. Duplicates happen, this question as such isn't terrible, and it has a _very_ useful list of duplicates now.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: True but circular. One cannot prove that the Poisson distribution has its density function in terms of $e$ without **already** using the exponential series in some way.

Answer (score 44):

- [Limit using Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121099)
- [Partial sums of exponential series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136996)
- [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248)
- [Calculate limit with summation index in formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268332)
- [Central value of the partial exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334224)
- [Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}$ if it exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493435)
- [Compare $e^n$ and its first $n$ terms sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574869)
- [Show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{-n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581125)
- [How can I compute this limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599919)
- [$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^k}{k!} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617475)
- [Limit of Series with Variable Lower Bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655074)
- [Weird limit $\lim \limits_{n\mathop\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\sum \limits_{k\mathop=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733656)
- [Is the sequences$\{S_n\}$ convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870524)
- [Summation of exponential series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909996)
- [Does n power of e grow much more faster than its Maclaurin polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946633)
- [Limit Challenge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998695)
- [Limits of sequences connected with real and complex exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118599)
- [The limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{T_n(n)}{e^n}$ where $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of $e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166061)
- [Limit of a series (Gamma distribution)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225118)

---

Also related:

- [Limit of an expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277037)

Comment: Just for you, I will ask the same question tomorrow :P

Comment: Oh wow, this is awesome.

Comment: hahaha, damn...