# How to prove that if $a_n=o(n) $ then $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_n^k}{k!}\sim e^{a_n} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

I recall a question where it was proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac12.$$This seems to remain true when $n$ is replaced by $n+c $ where $c$ is some constant, while apparently, if $a_n=o(n)$, $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_n^k}{k!}\sim e^{a_n}.$$How to prove it? Maybe the method used in the related question is also useful here, but I couldn't find it

Comment: I had a typo in the original post, where in the first display $a_n $ should have been $n $ - fixed now

Comment: Is $a_n > 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes

Comment: Perhaps it was [one of these questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1297573/5531) that you saw.

Comment: Why does this not tend to 1? Do you have the original proof?

Comment: @HenryLee see the link in my comment for many proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $0 < \varepsilon < e^{-1}$, choose $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $a_n < \varepsilon n$ for $n \geqslant N(\varepsilon)$. Then we have
\begin{align}
e^{a_n} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{a_n^k}{k!}
&= \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n^k}{k!} \\
&< \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(\varepsilon n)^k}{k!} \\
&< \varepsilon^{n+1}\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!} \\
&< \varepsilon^{n+1} e^n \\
&< \varepsilon
\end{align}
for $n \geqslant N(\varepsilon)$. So we even have
$$e^{a_n} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{a_n^k}{k!} \to 0\,,$$
not only
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{a_n^k}{k!} \sim e^{a_n}\,.$$

Comment: How is the step $e^{a_n} - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a_n^k}{k!}= \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}  \frac{a_n^k}{k!}$ motivated taking into account that $a_n$ is varying?

Comment: @gimusi It depends on $n$, but not on $k$.

Comment: But isn't it equivalent to assume $e^{a_n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n^k}{k!}$?

Comment: But that's a given. $$e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ is the definition of $e^x$. (Yes, it is possible to define it differently, then one needs to prove the power series expansion, but that's standard.)

Comment: Were you perhaps thinking about $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{a_k^k}{k!}\,,$$ @gimusi?

Comment: Yes of course, it wasn't clear at first that we are fixing $n$ and $a_n$. It is more clear now. Thanks